# Which filament slides past which?

Tags: human-biology

Somehow I haven't found anyone on the internet can answer this: during muscle contraction, does the thin myofilament slide past the stationary thick myofilament, or does the thick myofilament slide past the stationary thin myofilament?

Comment: think of it this way : the thin filaments are attached to the Z-line(with the help of Z -disc) and thick filaments with the help of a spring like protein(titin). Now, when contraction occurs, myosin head pulls the actin filament towards it (power stroke) : i.e. Z-line is pulled towards the centre and the length of sarcomere shortens. So, actin is pulled towards the centre : Thin filament slide over the thick ones. PS: I'll try to add a detailed ans later on. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an article on muscle contraction. It'll help to solve your problems. Especially read the part where the information about mechanism of power stroke is given (above figure 11.24).
Ask if you have furthur questions after reading this article!

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9961/

Answer (score 0):

thick filaments slide over thin as cross bridges are formed by thin filament which slides thick filament and sandwich like structure is formed and Z-line disappears

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you have any credible references however?

Comment: actually i read abou that in my state board textbook of biology

Comment: can you reference the textbook then?

Comment: i already reffered it and wrote answer

Comment: That's not a reference, what is the title of the book? Who is the author or publisher? What year was it published?